# Security level for local file in internet explorer

Tags: security, internet-explorer

Part of an application is inside a local html file that contains a java applet.
Whenever I try to access is the security bar pops up to ask me if I want to execute that content.

I lowered each and every security setting (internet, local and trusted zones) but it looks like local files (executed from c:\myapp\main.html) lives in their own "secret" zone.

I can't even add the file to the trusted sites because the ":" is not considered a valid char in the dialog box.

How can I do this? How can I stop the security bar to show for this file?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Would it help to share the relevant folder, and use the share name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced a similar issue with network applications using HTML help files.

Our resolution for this was to add the server (where the share files resided) directly into to the trusted sites list in internet explorer options.

Perhaps you could try adding in "localhost"  (remember to uncheck the "Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone").

You may find that you will experience this same issue though when deploying your application to your users on their computers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did not work for me.   I cannot open the file without a warning using c:\...   I had to create a share and access the files via the share name.   Clearly there need to be a way to add c:\temp\* to the trusted sites.   IE refuses to add that syntax to the trusted sites.

Answer (score 4):

> The zone for "My Computer" is normally hidden but it can be made
>   visible by editing the Registry so that this zone appears on the
>   Security tab in the Internet Options dialog box. The key that has to
>   be edited for a particular user account is
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\0
>
> The key to be edited if all user accounts are to have this zone
>   visible is
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\0
>
> Within the key is a DWORD value "Flags". Setting the data value of the
>   Flags value to 47 (in hexadecimal) causes the "My Computer"security
>   zone to be displayed. Setting the data value of the Flags value to 21
>   (in hexadecimal) causes the "My Computer" security zone to be hidden.

From http://surfthenetsafely.com/ieseczone3.htm

In fact, you only need to unset the bit 10 that the "2" represents.

Comment: Alas, it shows it in list but its property page doesn't work (in IE11, at least): when switching to it, the property page remains the same as the previously-selected entry.

Comment: As this answer is still relevant, the place to look for more info on the reg key is https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/182569/internet-explorer-security-zones-registry-entries-for-advanced-users and it is the 6th bit (the 32 value) that, when enabled, causes the zone to be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

go to Internet Explorer > Settings > Internet Options

- click "Advanced" tab
- scroll down to "Security" (about 2/3 of the way down)
- check box/enable "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer*"

This fixed the problem for me on Windows 10 running Internet Explorer for testing purposes - and now the "Active X" warning pop up no longer comes up, page loads with the content in question running.

Answer (score 0):

I found GDR's vital post very useful. I have sifted through reams and reams of internet forum posts recommending things such as:

(1) adding a website to the trusted zone
(2) adding local host to the trust zone
(3) adding a Mark of the Web tag to the HTML pages

But *none* of these solutions addressed my problem, but GDR's did.

Intranet security zone tweaks do not much help in the (admittedly exceptional) case of using the browser in a desktop app, but that is precisely what I need. I have a language lab full of machines that are not even connected to the internet most of the time, and I have no choice but to build a desktop app in JavaScript that runs in Internet Explorer to take advantage of IE's ADO objects that are used to access an Access database.

Microsoft has put a long gauntlet of safeguards to prevent you from doing this and absolutely the ONLY thing that can override these security measures (which are utterly irrelevant to my application) is to modify the "My Computer" zone, something which apparently used to be visible to everyone but which is invisible in Windows 7.

[image: "My Computer" security zone]

People ought to be warned about the risks of this procedure but not kept in the dark to suit some corporate objective Microsoft may have or just because someone wants an inexpensive means of signaling that they belong to the tribe of experts. Wagging your finger and saying "don't do this" is the cheapest possible way to engage in this kind of signaling. It does not contribute to the information ecosystem. This solution was critical to my particular business requirement (one size shoe does not fit all).

Comment: In relation to your feedback about voting, we have a culture here that people may vote for any reason, and that there is no value in guessing why someone voted the way they did. I get an unexplained downvote every few weeks - it happens. Note that an upvote is worth more than a downvote though, so small numbers of DVs can mostly be ignored.